# Calling functions in HTML forms

Tags: javascript, html, function, forms

Having significant problems making a simple link between a form's buttons and javaScript functions.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for Linux (vers 6 November 2007), see www.w3.org" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Examples of Strings</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
// declarations
//]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Basic Calculator</h1>

<form action="form_action.asp" method="get">
  First Variable: <input type="text" name="tb1" /><br />
  Second Variable: <input type="text" name="tb2" /><br />
  Result: <input type="text" name="result" /><br />
  <input type="button" name="b1" value="Submit" onclick="myAdd()" /><br />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[



<asp:Button id="b1" runat="server" OnClick="documment.myAdd()"></asp:Button>



function myAdd(tb1, tb2){

    var result = tb1 + tb2;
    alert(result);
    return result;
}




//]]>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Button (b1) should return the values at tb1 and tb2. Note: ultimately it should represent the value at tb3, but for the purposes of debugging  tb3 is doing nothing at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

In a browser environment, `window` is the global object, not `document`.

You can also omit it, and the scope is automatically resolved to `window`.

Also, you aren't passing the arguments to your function. You should just give them an `id` attribute and reference that using `document.getElementById()`.

Something like this should do it (provided you add the `id` attribute as per code)...

```
window.onload = function() {

    document.getElementById('my-form').onsubmit = function() {

        document.getElementById('result').value = parseInt(document.getElementById('tb1').value, 10) + parseInt(document.getElementById('tb1').value, 10);

        return false;
    };

};
```

Comment: Thanks. Would there be any chance you might expand both aspects of what you just said (both in relation to the document and the getter)?